# MinimumSizeCompression is not working with serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-plugins

I'm using the new [serverless compression option](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/5529) using minimumCompressionSize = 1KB.
Everything works fine on payloads > 1KB, yet payload <1KB are also compressed.

It's like the minimumCompressionSize remains 0 whatever value I choose (See image Below)

here is my serverless.yml:

```
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1
  apiGateway:
    minimumCompressionSize: 1024
...
```

Have you encountered this problem? How can I solve it without manually updating the api-gateway configuration on aws?

Thank you in advance.

I followed this guide: https://medium.com/@OneMuppet_/gzip-deflate-content-from-aws-api-gateway-using-serverless-36e208da4270

and tried what is in the official documentation:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#compression

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to override the cloudformation template [Override AWS CloudFormation Resource](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources#override-aws-cloudformation-resource) ?

you can specify a custom ressource with your provider name where you override the properties `MinimumCompressionSize` of `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`

Example (serverless.yaml) :

```
service: my-awesome-project-to-duplicate-pizzas

provider:
  name: aws
  ...
```

you can add:

```
Resources:
    aws:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
        Properties:
            MinimumCompressionSize: 1024
```

links that can help :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-serverless.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-minimumcompressionsize

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. this worked. But the [serverless compression] (https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/5529) is not working.